# Application.properties in parent and child projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to load child project's properties in parent project.

- parent
  --------/application.properties
- child
  --------/application.properties

Is it possible to add child's properties as property source in parent project?

More important question, it this property file from child project visible in parent project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `resources/META-INF` folder to your child project and add files  `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` and `spring.factories` to prime the auto configuration pump for parent projects.  See Spring Boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).

I think the two should be orthogonal.  Repetition is always a bad idea.

Comment: can you provide more details? The link you are provided - I could not find *additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json*